# Java-based desktop application to control ROS

Tags: ros, gui, java

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to program GUI for controlling ROS as java-based desktop application

I know that I may need to use rosjava, but I didn't find any tutorial that demonstrate how to use it.

Can someone help?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203301/java-based-desktop-application-to-control-ros/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-17**:
Is Java a strict requirement, or are you just looking for an easy way to put together a GUI for controlling ROS apps? Have you looked into [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt)?

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-02-17**:
Java is not a mandatory requirement. But why not Java? I will take a look at rqt but also i wanted to know why rqt but not java? Thanks

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-02-18**:
Also, can i Connect to a database using rqt?

**Comment by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on 2015-02-18**:
Thank you Tom. How can I use these plugins? I'm beginner in using ROS.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-02-18**:
The [rqt wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/) has a [list](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins) of available plugins and a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin) on how to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt` was designed to allow you to rapidly throw together a GUI for your ROS-based robot. It already has a bunch of plugins written for it, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. I don't know if there's a plugin for connecting to databases, but you could always write one.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1